# Volley in Android M developer preview: org.apache.http cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-volley, android-mnc

I'm testing Volley's HurlStack in Android M Developer Preview.

After I change `compileSdkVersion` from `22` to `'android-MNC'`, all classes from org.apache.http are not compiled:

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine;
```

How can I modify my code to solve this problem?

I know there're some changes related to Apache HTTP client, but it still doesn't work when I follow the steps to add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in gradle.

Reference: [HurlStack.java AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/c3dea925af9b3523e2e01e8b7799e71ef558c1c5/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HurlStack.java)

[Behavior Changes: Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Comment: Apache HttpClient has been deprecated for a while. Volley uses HttpClient on old versions of Android, URLConnection on new versions. It may well be that they have removed httpclient from M preview alltogether. The error should not occur when you set your minimum version of android to a level where Volley uses URLConnection.

Comment: or you can include httpClient yourself. Like from here: https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/

Comment: @Christine Thank you for your answer. From https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html section "Update an existing project", Google suggests the minSdkVersion should be set to 'MNC'. I wonder if there's an official way to bypass this.

Comment: Volley is in your IDE as a source project. You can remove the call to httpclient there. The code is in "newRequestQueue()" in Volley.java

Comment: It seems like the app can be run on Developer Preview 2. I added useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' and changed the gradle version to 1.3.0-beta4. IDE still cannot resolve the library though. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official “Behaviour Changes” document [states](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) that the Apache HTTP client is removed in Android M — not deprecated, but **removed**. Personally I highly suggest switching to [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) which actually is used as a `HttpURLConnection` engine since KitKat, by using a dependency you get all fresh goodies from Square team directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore these warns, because Volley is still compiled using API 22:
https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/gradle.properties

add these in proguard configuration:
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using okHttp, the fallback is to use legacy apache httpclient as suggested by Google.
See my answer here to get it working.

[How to use the legacy Apache HTTP client on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-m)

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, the only reason you were including HttpClient is because you were testing HTTP response codes:

```
if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {}
```

then a simple fix is just to use the version of the constants that are in the HttpURLConnection class:

```
if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {}
```

Comment: But note that not all the Http status codes are present in the HttpURLConnection class. For instance 307 for a temporary redirect is not present anymore.