# I have updated Android API to 23 and there is no error in any xml file but when I try to build project this shows R cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, r.java-file

I had update latest Android API i.e. 23 and its build tools also and when I want to try with this API and build my android project it shows R symbol cannot be resolved.

So, please help me regarding this and I also want to use org.apache.http for HTTPResponse class so which jar I have to use , please tell me regarding this also.

I have tried all the tricks like build and clean the project and close the project and reopen again and I verified also that there is no error in xml file also.

Comment: eclipse or android studio?

Comment: I am using android studio

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but

Comment: I have checked it but in his case built has been succeeded but in my case build also fails.

Comment: can you post error log?

Comment: I have updated error log with my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88980/discussion-between-varnit-khandelwal-and-sasikumar).

Comment: Helpfull if you paste your build.gradle.

Comment: I have also paste my build.gradle file also

Comment: buildToolsVersion '21.1.2' is not 23 API level

Comment: Yes this I know this is not for API 23 as I changed it and try to build with API 21 but then also I got the same error

Comment: Try changing `compileSdkVersion` to `23` and clean your project.

Comment: I also tried it but getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

In addition to previous answers. I see a lot of classes from apache lib:
HttpPost, BasicNameValuePair and others. That was [removed in M](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

Comment: But then If I want use these classes in Android M then how can I use.

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-m

Comment: @VarnitKhandelwal For my project I was forced to migrate to OkHttp library, because all of the solutions provided didn't work

Comment: how to migrate to OkHttp library can you please help me.

Comment: They use this in license vending, have they upgraded this to for M?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio) is similar question. Your problem is not in R cannot be resolved. Problem is in the `org.apache.http` package which was removed in SDK 23.

Answer (score 0):

change your buildToolsVersion 22.0.1

again your compile version is lower than targeted version

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this error occurs the general solution is `Clean your project` and if still an error reapeats `close the Eclipse once and reopen it`.

That way my same problem got sloved.... :)