# Project Not working after updating to API 23

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can anyone please help me with this? I dont know what does this mean.
To give you a back up I updated my sdk with 23 and then i got 101 errors regarding HTTPClient not being resolved. So i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433687/android-gradle-apache-httpclient-does-not-exist) link to remove that then I have this error of which i have no clue where to start with.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output F:\sagarDevanga\workspace\AndNrby\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=F:\sagarDevanga\workspace\AndNrby\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have updated the question's title also so that other people also find it useful.So I will write a detailed answer about how this error occured in my project and the fixes I did and how I finally derived the answer.

1) I updated the SDK and then started to compile my project using the latest api i.e API 23. You can do that by going to **File -> Project Structure ->Select your module**.
Now in the right hand side window under properties the top two properties can be changed using in the drop down.[image]
Then click on Apply and Ok.

2) So when you do this your app's build.gradle file will look like this[image]. And now everything looks good. It will compile also. But when you run the project you will get a lot of errors by this name **Error:(17, 35) error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist** Obviously if you are using them in your async tasks.

3) So when i got this error I did a lot of research here and there and then came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432785/i-have-updated-android-api-to-23-and-there-is-no-error-in-any-xml-file-but-when) and added the HTTP CLIENTS jar files in the libs folder and then tried to run the program I ended up with this problem (problem mentioned in the question).

4) So after diggin around I found that the problem was HTTP methods which i used in the Async task were deprecated in the API 23 hence I landed myself in this mess.

5) Then what I did next fixed the problem for me. Refernce given [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

6) In your module's build.gradle file add this line **useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'** like below.[image]

7) Wait your still not done. Now go to your main build.gradle file and add this line  **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'** like this [image]. Now build and compile your project everything runs fine.

8) After all this steps the project works fine but I have a doubt in the last pic that i shared which is of the top level build.gradle file. Whether I should keep both the classpaths or just use this **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'** and remove the other one. If any one have any idea on this please help.

9) The problem was that they deprecated the HTTP Clients in the Latest Android API 23. Insted of HTTP Client you have to use HttpUrlConnection but if you want to continue using HTTP client for NOW follow the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your adt supports the version of api that you are running. See this link : https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: Thanx a lot. I have answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

To fix you should check in libs (.jar) and in your build.gradle if there are some libraries duplicated. This error happen tipicaly when you add a copy of the same library or a library that include a copy of another library that you have already added

Update also your support libs from SDK

Comment: Thanx a lot. I have answered the question.