# How do I fix the lint in android studio after allowing legacy code?

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

As we all are aware, Android removed support for org.apache.http after version 22. There is a switch in the app wide gradle build file which allows people to continue using it,

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    ...

    // enable org.apache.http
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

However, when I include code like

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
```

that still shows up underlined in red in android studio, despite compiling without errors. Everywhere I use NameValuePair also shows up in red. It makes it very difficult to sort legitimate errors from fake ones. In some of our source, which we can't afford to update yet, the entire right hand side of the screen next to the scrollbar is near solid red, all fake errors.

How do I correct this? It's really annoying.

EDIT: I'd like to add that the advice here, [How to use the legacy Apache HTTP client on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-m) , does not actually solve my problem. My problem is with Android studio's *editor* ; this is not an actual compile *or* runtime problem.

Comment: I want to add that closing android studio and opening it again does get rid of the red for the entire file. However, if I make the mistake of opening a file that uses org.apache.http for editing, that file will forever be red until I open android studio again.

Comment: Did you look at this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-m

Comment: @buzeeg yes I did, I have a different problem but thanks for linking it as it's related. I tried that solution; it did not actually solve my problem with regard to Android studio's editor.

Comment: while regarding best answer (and its first comment), it seems that the first answer's proposal would fix your issue (move jar in your lib folder and compile it)

Comment: After reading more carefully the linked question and a few comments, it seems to be a bug in Android Studio

Comment: @buzeeg, since it is unlikely anyone will come up with an `@Suppress` that I haven't tried - those only work on classes, methods, or members anyway - I think your comment is about the best answer to my question I am likely to get, and I think if it were an official answer it would help other people with my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in Android Studio, which have not been released yet: [Issue 183668: new useLibrary mechanism not supported in Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detailhttps://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183668)