# How to add compile time dependency in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache, httpurlconnection

In the developer.android.com site I saw the below information under the Android 6.0 changes.

**Apache HTTP Client Removal**

---

Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

android {
   `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy` 
}

Problem:

I am using eclipse and have used the HTTP client. To use the new  HttpURLConnection how can I add the dependency in Eclipse IDE? Or I have to use the Android Studio to use this new feature?

Thanks for looking and giving solution to this problem.

Comment: You should use Android Studio not only for this for all future support

Comment: @SENTHILKUMAR S : I think this libraray will be in `Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional` folder..

Comment: @SENTHILKUMAR S : Here is my path for library :E:\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\optional...Yours should be like this..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@SENTHILKUMAR S** You should use ***`Android Studio`*** .

**useLibrary** adds the library to classpath while compiling but does not bundle the library with the application. Courtesy **@laalto** Sir .

Please upgrade the **Gradle tools version in your build.gradle** file of *Android Studio* , as follows:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' //2.3.0
}
```

For more info you can check

> [How to add Apache HTTP API (legacy) as compile-time dependency to build.grade for Android M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `org.apache.http.legacy` to your libs folder.

This jar will be found from

> Your SDK path \android-sdk\platforms\android-23\optional

Copy file from here and add it to your libs folder.

Also it would be better if you use `Android Studio`.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

For those stuck using Eclipse (ie. open-source project you do not own), here is a solution for using org.apache.http.legacy, as per the **original question**.

> Insert this inside the application tag on the manifest file, on all
>   project instances that uses the legacy apache classes:
>
> ```
> <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
> ```

Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33512294/461982