# Android Gradle Unable to Find Apache Library

Tags: android, apache, android-studio, gradle

When I try to sync gradle, it shows this error.

```
Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy
```

My build.gradle:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.mynamespace"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 17
    versionName "1.7"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

   compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

My root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I tried to use gradle 1.3.1 and buildToolsVersion 23.0.2 but it didn't work. There aren't many questions like this and they didn't resolved out. So I needed to ask this question to come to a fine end.

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-m.

Comment: @LongPhan that does not work.

Comment: I also have this issue and fixed it by removing the line `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` from the module `build.gradle`. Give that a try. If not, try some of the suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914589/gradle-failed-to-sync-with-unable-to-find-optional-library). Good luck!

Comment: It didn't work. I need 'org.apache.http.legacy' in my project. This is really a Android Studio bug, because all of my collegues have the same project that is working fine in their computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem before and the way I solved it was by copying the JAR into the `libs/` folder of your project, Gradle will not resolve this jar automatically.

You should have a copy in your local machine already under `SDK/platforms/android-23/optional`

Comment: I have to accept this answer because this is not the exact solution, it is a workaround. This is an absulately Gradle bug and needs to be solved.