# Gradle failed to sync with 'unable to find optional library'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I had to reinstall my system and today I get this error in Android Studio when I try to sync with gradle:

```
Warning: Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy
```

My project gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And my module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

[From the google docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client):

> To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the
>   following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> android {
>     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
> }
> ```

I tried the suggestions mention in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-m) but they don't work. Same result with android studio 1.5 and 2 preview.

How can I fix this?

**Edit**: Things I've tried so far:

1. Change gradle classpath versions to 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.5.0.
2. Change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 22. Also the buildToolsVersion from 23.0.1, 23.0.0, 22.0.1.

Comment: `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'` use this ,For testing case

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya same error with that version of the `buildToolsVersion`.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me is from this thread [Why Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy occurs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898857/why-warningunable-to-find-optional-library-org-apache-http-legacy-occurs)

Comment: I got the same error message with double/multiple declaration of `org.apache.http.legacy` library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Top level build.gradle - /build.gradle

```
buildscript {
...
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
}
}
```

Module specific build.gradle - /app/build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
...
}
```

Add org.apache.http.legacy.jar which is in **Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional** folder to **app/libs** directory and sync your project

Comment: Yes and afterwards it says to add a compile-time dependency which I mentioned in my post.

Comment: So use HttpUrlConnection instead, Apache HTTP client is dead

Comment: add it in libs and sync your project...that might work

Comment: I will accept this because the only way I managed to make it work is by including the jar. BTW I had to remove the offending line. Thanks john!

Comment: thnx, Yes , necessary to add org.apache.http.legacy.jar in lib folder

Comment: Then if you add the jar to the "lib" folder then not necessary to add "useLibrary" to the gradle script.

Comment: Error everywhere glasspath version !

Comment: While the compile versions were not relevant, the last sentence: "Add org.apache.http.legacy.jar " solved my problem!

Answer (score 9):

After a lot of working this solutions work for me 
.
** Studio\Android\sdk\platforms** here delete your android-23 and from sdk manager update api 23 again.** 
.
it will solve your issue.

Comment: I wonder how it is not the accepted answer, it is really the correct solution, I tried a lot to find solution for this problem and I used all methods written in the internet, this is the only solution that solved my same problem

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it didn't work because I was missing `optional.json` in `<sdk-path>\platforms\android-23\optional\`, directory with the following content:

```
[
  {
    "name": "org.apache.http.legacy",
    "jar": "org.apache.http.legacy.jar",
    "manifest": false
  }
]
```

Creating a new JSON file with with above content solved the problem for me.

Comment: In my case, I had the folder android-23 with all the content, and the folder ...\optional\ had the jar, but  not the file 'optional.json' . So as @notsopopularguy said, I just created it, and refreshed AS. Worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` jar file in your Android Stuido project's ***app/libs*** folder.

```
  Jar Location - `<SDK LOCATION>\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\optional`
```

To do this, just right click on your project and select `Show in Explorer` then go to `...\app\libs` and paste above *jar* file and ***Sync your Project with Gradle File***

`Module:app`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "<ur_app_id>"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your project gradle file to use gradle version 1.3.1.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

Also try adding codehause repo.

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven{
            url 'http://repository.codehaus.org'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Already tried it, does not work. I also tried the latest version which is `1.5.0` I believe and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was actually occurring because I didn't have the correct SDK installed on that computer. Navigating to `.../Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23` I could see that folder was empty. Adding SDK 23 via the SDK manager fixed the problem and allowed me to compile.

You should manually check that you have the same version of the SDK installed that is specified under `compileSdkVersion` in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

To save time 2 solutions are best and works for me.

**Solution 1 :**

open your android sdk manager and reinstall API 23 (remove and install again).

**Solution 2 :**

Download this file which contain `optional.json` file
extract and move optional.json to :

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional

Answer (score 0):

if above solution is not work then try this way

I experienced this problem recently, and it is caused by the path length restriction I think it´s 256 characters maximum.

Relocate your Project and the build will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy "**sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar**" to your    app module libs directory, then add as library;
2. If you enable the proguard, please edit "**proguard-rules.pro**" to keep related classes or exception will occurred.