# HttpClient not working in my android studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

First sorry for my bad English  I am new to android studio 1.4 ,I am getting error in HttpClient

Error

```
C:\Users\madhu\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginAndsign\app\src\main\java\com\login\loginandsign\SimpleHttpClient.java

Error:(27, 20) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient

Error:(34, 20) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient

Error:(36, 31) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient

Error:(40, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable ConnManagerParams


Error:(57, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient

Error:(58, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost

Error:(58, 36) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost

Error:(59, 13) error: cannot find symbol class UrlEncodedFormEntity

Error:(59, 51) error: cannot find symbol class UrlEncodedFormEntity

Error:(96, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient

Error:(97, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet

Error:(97, 35) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet
```

I added below dependency but still it showing same error

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.6'
compile files('libs/core.jar')
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio

Comment: Hi ,thanq fr your quick responce,i tried that one but i gt this error         compile files('libs/core.jar')                                                     Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Comment: Post your build.gradle total

Answer (score 3):

`HttpClient` was [removed in Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

To continue using `HttpClient`, add code below to your `build.gradle`:

```
 android{
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

Please check **[HttpClient won't import in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio)**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' 


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion // set yours 
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11 //Yours
        versionName "0.1" // Yours
    }

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.6'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile files('libs/core.jar')
}
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync** Your Project .

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line in dependencies

```
 compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

might be you didn't upgrade your gradle plugin in root build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' 
        // Lowest version for useLibrary is 1.3.0
        // Android Studio will notify you about the latest stable version
        // See all versions: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using target sdk as 23 add below code in your build.grade
   **Module specific build.gradle - /app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
     ...
       }

and change your buildscript to
**Top level build.gradle - /build.gradle**

   buildscript {
...
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
}
}
```

[For More Information please check this android dev link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Comment: where i need to put  
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' line please tell me @Er Pragati Singh

Comment: after doing that i am getting this error  Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy @Er Pragati Singh

Comment: just reinstall API 23 (remove and install again).

Comment: please check hope it help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914589/gradle-failed-to-sync-with-unable-to-find-optional-library)

Comment: how to reinstall Api 23 in android studio

Comment: go to SDK like in mac /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk  or select project and click **FILE MENU -> PROJECT STRUCTURE** you will found SDK location and check above link just click in link

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added library and recompiled but still not working then

Check if you have `android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-23\optional\optional.json` in the particular place.

If not then just remove API 23 and install that again, that will work.