# Android studio Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpClient'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an Android Project and I need to use an http call.

I use this simply code:

```
public void onGetClick(View v) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.d("WM.ALS", line);
    }

}
```

but I cannot find the HttpClient library.

I added into dir /lib the .jar file downloaded from Apache (http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and into 
the "build.gradle(Module: app)" file, i added:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-4.4.3'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-4.5.1'
```

}

But still don't work..

How do I do?

Comment: Why don't use `HttpURLConnection`?

Comment: I did not think about it

Comment: Why to use extra(Deprecated) library when `HttpURLConnection` provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 10):

Add this in build.gradle (Module:app)

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

its working

Answer (score 4):

1. You are using `appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` .**HttpClient** deprecated in here .

**HttpClient** is not supported in **SDK 23** .You need to use **URLConnection**.

> An URLConnection for HTTP (RFC 2616) used to send and receive data over the web. Data may be of any type and length. This class may be
>   used to send and receive streaming data whose length is not known in
>   advance.

Please check **[HttpClient won't import in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio)**

You can use `org.apache.http.legacy`

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If
>   your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or
>   higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more
>   efficient because it reduces network use through transparent
>   compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To
>   continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the
>   following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
       }
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Sync** .Hope this helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053335/httpclient-not-working-in-my-android-studio-1-4?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @Rushabh042

```
    android{
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
            useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
           }
```

will work like a charm...!
Or you can do this by this way too:

Android studio->File->Project Structure->(Select your app in Modules section left side)Dependencies tab->Add dependency

Search for `org.apache.http.legacy`
and you can select from the searched list.

Rebuild your app and there you go... :)

Happy Coding