# useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When i use this in gradle it is showing as

"Error:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy"

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

......

}
```

Project Level :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: show me your gradle file of Project level;

Comment: @RjzSatvara.....added...Check it

Comment: @cricket_007..... i had tried the solution already but couldn't solve it

Comment: Alright, then. Do you really need the legacy Apache HTTP, though? Why not compile this one? https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

Answer (score -1):

Add org.apache.http.legacy.jar which is in **Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional** folder to **app/libs** directory and sync your project.
Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914589/gradle-failed-to-sync-with-unable-to-find-optional-library) as this question looks similar.

Comment: Can i get a link a link from where i can download that particular jar....i couldnt find the jar

Comment: @Teja That `Android/Sdk/platforms` is the link. It depends where you've installed the SDK.

Comment: Okay; but why do this? And why isn't `useLibrary` (the documented solution) working?