# How to use apache http on Android P

Tags: java, android, apache-httpcomponents

When I run my app in *Android P* devices, I get some error like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.le.android.client.LeApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.le.android.client.LeApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.le.android.client-uvQkO641-__8Z_p2oT0t7g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.le.android.client-uvQkO641-__8Z_p2oT0t7g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.le.android.client-uvQkO641-__8Z_p2oT0t7g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1009)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5836)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.le.android.client.LeApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.le.android.client-uvQkO641-__8Z_p2oT0t7g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.le.android.client-uvQkO641-__8Z_p2oT0t7g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.le.android.client-uvQkO641-__8Z_p2oT0t7g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:50)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1120)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1001)
... 9 more
```

How should I use the library `org.apache.http.legacy` in *Android P*?

Answer (score 15):

I read the [Android P behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p),and I get some messages:

> Apache HTTP client deprecation
>   With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client. 
>   Beginning with Android P, that library is removed from the 
>   bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.
>
> **To continue using the Apache HTTP client, 
>   apps that target Android P and above must add the following to their AndroidManifest.xml:**
>
> *<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>*
>
> Note: The android:required="false" attribute is required for apps that have a minimum SDK of 23 or lower, because on devices with API levels lower than 24, the org.apache.http.legacy library is not available. (On those devices, the Apache HTTP classes are available on the bootclasspath.)

Comment: Even after adding this...my app still crash with the same error @scott

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, I thought I just needed to add the useLibrary thing in the gradle file.

Answer (score 4):

To run org.apache.http.legacy perfectely in Android 9.0 Pie create an xml file `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
      <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
      </base-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

And add 2 tags tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

> android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
>
> android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest......>
  <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
   <activity..../> 
   ......
   ......
 <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false"/>
</application>
```

Also add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in your app build gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your application id"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: Following your instruction I got the following error:
`ERROR: Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy`

Comment: It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914589/gradle-failed-to-sync-with-unable-to-find-optional-library