# Android: NoClassDefFoundError happening only to a certain user

Tags: android

Full stack trace on Crashlytics:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "cbny" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-IyfVa31mzP0zVZRBUk1v3g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.gms-IyfVa31mzP0zVZRBUk1v3g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-IyfVa31mzP0zVZRBUk1v3g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
       at srv.verify(:com.google.android.gms@19831030@19.8.31 (100408-284611645):1)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:1484)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1424)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1368)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:219)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:325)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:488)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
       at repackaged.com.android.volley.toolbox.f.b(:21)
       at repackaged.com.android.volley.toolbox.f.a(:38)
       at repackaged.com.android.volley.toolbox.f.a(:95)
       at repackaged.com.android.volley.toolbox.a.a(:27)
       at repackaged.com.android.volley.g.run(:39)
```

Nobody else but only one user who uses Samsung Galaxy A8 (Android 9) is going through this.

I'm using a third-party code obfuscator, AppSuit. I've asked the company about AppSuit could potentially produce different output or cause different behaviors with different users, but they said that would be impossible.

I can't even get a clue why this is happening, and have no idea how to track and troubleshoot this issue. Any advice or ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50446148/how-to-use-apache-http-on-android-p

Comment: also check your dependency versions and update to latest stable release.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel Many of other users use Android 9+ devices, but none of them have this issue. My test device is on Android 10 too. Do you have any guesses on why this is not happening to the others?

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel I'll take that into account anyway. Thanks!