# Warning: Unable to find org.apache.http.lagecy.jar

Tags: java, android

I have tried with the following code. I have used to "useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy' in build.gradle's android part but error is still appearing , and I have also org.apache.http.legacy.jar in \Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bhuvneshgautam.cityretails"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

[image][image]
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I think duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-marshmallow

Comment: Duplicate question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

block then copy jar and paste into your_application/app/libs/ then include compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) in dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    ...
}
```

then clean and rebuild the project