# Android: Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'

Tags: android, build, interface-builder, android-gradle-plugin, build-process

I am currently facing a problem when I change the targetSDK version from 21 to 23.

After changing and the build the gradle, When I try to run the application am getting an error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
 > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
 Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value
```

In my lib folder I have a library called **org.apache.http.legacy**

This library i added when change the sdk version from 21 to 23 , because in 23 it is depricated.

- Sync: OK
- Make Project: OK
- Clean: OK
- Run: Error

My gradle file is

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23

}
```

In my lib folder i have

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- x86
- android-support-v4.jar
- gcm.jar
- json.jar
- org.apache.http.legacy.jar
- tint.jar
- webproc.jar

Can any please help me to resolve the error **Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.finished with non-zero exit value 2**

I heard that it may because of jar issue. several times i delete and paste new jar from **Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional**. But still facing the same issue

Can anyone please help me

Comment: I am not sure this is the exact reason basically "non-zero exit value 2" this will occur when you have duplicate libraries in your project. Can u tell me what are all jar's do u have in libs? only org.apache.http.legacy ?

Comment: try possible solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31653002/1168654

Comment: Please see the updated question i add all jar and files in lib folder @Raghavendra

Comment: I guess you have tried this, If not can u please try remove android-support-v4.jar lib

Comment: Thank you, as you said i remove V4 support library now its working  @ Raghavendra

Comment: @BinilS can I post it as answer will u accept  It could help others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove V4 support library because you are already using appcompat-v7.