# substitute for apache.http.client library

Tags: android, xml, database, android-layout

I'm new to Android programming and I'm trying to connect my android app to a mysql database using the library: `apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar`

as shown in this tutorial 
[here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html) . I am using the Marshmellow API (23). I've noticed many questions asking for workarounds and it seems that this library is no longer supported according to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-marshmallow).
I have the suggested workarounds to no avail.
Are there any other compatible libraries that I can use that have good user support/tutorials/guides etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `HttpURLConnection` It supports modern SSL(SNI) and very easy to use. See this documentation for a full implementation of a networked App example.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html