# Using minifyEnabled true getting errors

Tags: android

**Error**

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2' in line 16 of file
> >     'E:\Dipali**********\app\proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Please show your proguard rules file

Comment: Actually i didn't write any proguard rule......if possible can you tell me which rules i have to use to shrink my signed APK file

Comment: @cricket_00_ I write this line in my proguard "-dontwarn org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2"

Comment: You tried to write a gradle-dependency in your proguard file. Write the classnames (using wildcards) into your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
-dontwarn org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2
```

with

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

Comment: :Thanks for reply but still i am getting errors like Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Comment: This error seems not related to your origin question. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-marshmallow