# image not showing in networkimageview for first load

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a `NetworkImageView` which has to show image once I click a button. When I click the button for the first time it doesn't display the image but if I click it second time then its showing the image.

I have set default image for it and it shows that image for first click of button but if I click it again then it shows the image form the url.

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = mInstance.getImageLoader();
imageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(img, R.drawable.placeholder, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
img.setImageUrl(url, mInstance.getImageLoader());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download an Image by using Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104831/how-to-download-an-image-by-using-volley)

Comment: @inner_class7 I don't know how it's a duplicate question, I am not asking about the way to download image using volley, I just wanted to know, what could be the reason for this behavior of NetworkImageView. If you can't help or can't understand my question don't simply tag it as a duplicate question.

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of activity? Like the part of setting onClickListener to button, which url is used.

Answer (score -2):

Is the use of NetworkImageView mandatory? If not, you should try using Picasso library: http://square.github.io/picasso/ . It's super easy to use!

Answering your question using picasso:

You can use a normal ImageView, then, onClick you fetch the image you want, nad inflate your view with the following method:

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask for _how_ to load image from network. This doesn't answer _why_ OP's method doesn't work in manner s/he described.