# Show Image in Android as a result of REST API Respone Header

Tags: android, image, rest, header, android-volley

My REST API is returning an image in the header ('Content-Type', 'image/png'). The image is stored as binary in SQL Server (data type: picture, stored in binary format). API's response is perfect as I have checked in Postman.

I want to display that image in Android. (I am using volley for Network requests.)
Any thoughts?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT1**

Here is my slim REST API route that returns the image.

```
//get image
 $app->get('/image', function ($request, $response) {
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:server =localhost; Database = dbName', 'dbUser', 'dbPass');
$sql = "SELECT Picture 
        FROM Table
        WHERE Primary_Key = 'abc'";

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')->write($row['Picture']);}
```

**EDIT2**

Here is my API get request call using volley at Android end. This code resides in a Fragment. url is a String variable, profileImage is an ImageView where I want to use that fetched image.

```
url= getString(R.string.api_url) + "image";
    request = new StringRequest(GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            byte[] byteArray = response.getBytes();
            Bitmap bitmap = 
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } //onErrorResponse
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
    };
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    queue.add(request);
```

Comment: `My REST API is returning an image in the header ('Content-Type', 'image/png'). `. No. That is a content type. A string. Some characters.

Comment: My GET API call(http://localhost/api/image) is returning the image. I can't get this image in Android via volley

Comment: I see no code..

Comment: Please post some code how you are trying to achieve it?

Comment: @blackapps and Android_id : I am working on the question to put some code. I have just edited the question and inserted code for the API. Thank you.

Comment: @blackapps I have added code for both API end and Android end.

Comment: `//below line gives error on response,`. Yes. And already at compile time as response is a string and not a stream.

Comment: I know that is a string. How should I populate my ImageView?

Comment: I have updated onResponse()  code. Now I can't see the image in ImageView.

Comment: I think First you will have to decode the string  i.e,the response something like byte [] byteArray = Base64.decode(response,Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:1
Also, if I try to store the hardcoded binary of the image in the byte[] , it gives me error. Integer Number too large. It has more than 65k characters.

Comment: Here is the image that is stored in SQL Server in Picture format.
https://rizwanabbasi.com/image.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of effort, I came to conclusion that this question is possible duplicate of
[How to download an Image by using Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104831/how-to-download-an-image-by-using-volley/41112901)

I replaced the value of
url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbujt.png";
with my API GET request and result is perfectly as desired.

Here is the code from that question thread.

```
ImageView mImageView;
String url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbujt.png";
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
...

// Retrieves an image specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}, 0, 0, null,
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
    }
});
// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Thank you all for helping.