# Apache commons dependency not excluded in gradle | Android

Tags: android, gradle, janrain

I have a library project [(Janrain:Jump)](https://github.com/janrain/jump.android) that uses the `org.apache.http.legacy` library. When I try to build my project I get the duplicate error like following:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/codec/StringEncoderComparator.class
```

So I figured that the `org.apache.commons` are duplicate entry because Janrain uses it and it's also included in the Android 24 (as an external library). So I tried to remove the commons from the :Jump gradle like:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
}
```

Now, I'd expect that this removes `org.apache.commons` but I still get the duplicate entry gradle error.

Here is the :Jump gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    //If building with strict Android 6.0 the following will need to be uncommented
    //See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html
    //And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-m
    useLibrary "org.apache.http.legacy"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        // replace the below string with your own Google client ID. Make sure this is consistent
        // with the values used in openid_appauth_idp_configs.xml
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                <my values>]
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-apache:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
    compile 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the `org.apache.commons` not excluded even when I include it in configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this task to your build.gradle then run `gradle findDuplicates` to find the jars

```
task findDuplicates {
    doLast {
        def findMe = 'org/apache/commons/codec/StringEncoderComparator.class'
        configurations.runtime.asFileTree.matching {
            include '**/*.jar'
        }.files.each { File jarFile ->
            zipTree(jarFile).visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
                if (fvd.path == findMe) {
                    println "Found $findMe in $jarFile.name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, figured out what was adding the duplicate and it's now fixed.